# 24vAC to Multiple DC Supplies

Tags: power-supply, 24v

I am trying to put together a power circuit which will take a 24vAC supply to the following DC supplies.

- +24vDC (700mA) - Powering DC relays and OpAmps.
- +5vDC (500mA) - Powering MCU, Ethernet etc.
- +3.3vDC (150mA) - Powering MCU.

I'm thinking of using the following setup

`24vAC -> Bridge Rectifier -> 24v MC78M24BTG Linear Regulator ->
                          -> 5v LM2596 Switching Regulator -> 3.3v LM317 LDO ->.`

Is this the best way forward for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 24Vac then after rectification and smoothing this will be more like 32Vdc or maybe 33Vdc. The first thing you need to do is reduce that to 24Vdc for powering the relays and op-amps. I'd use a switcher because using a linear (at 700mA) is going to dissipate 6.3 watts.

In fact I'd use switchers for all the rails (all powered from the raw 32Vdc voltage).

If the 24V dc rail needs to be fairly "quiet" for the op-amps I might consider using a switcher to generate 25Vdc then a LDO linear regulator to take 25Vdc to 24Vdc (this would dissipate about 1 watt in total).

Alternatively, if the op-amps were only using 50mA (guesswork) I'd generate two 24V rails - one for the relays (bulk of the 700mA current) and one for the op-amps but it depends on the mix of currents and I can't realistically guess what that is.